# Установка poetry в Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, poetry

Установила poetry, но при выполнении команды в терминале (например poetry show) получаю ошибку:

> poetry : Имя "poetry" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильность написания имени, а также наличие и правильност
> ь пути, после чего повторите попытку.
> строка:1 знак:1
>
> +poetry show
>
> +~~~~~~
>
> +CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (poetry:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>
> +FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Она решается с помощью выполнния команды в терминале: `$Env:Path += ";C:\Users\tatyana\AppData\Roaming\Python\Scripts"; setx PATH "$Env:Path"`, но ее надо выполнять при каждом запуске Pycharm.

Во время создания проекта путь до poetry.exe указан
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы не приходилось каждый раз напрямую задавать путь в терминале?

- PyCharm 2021.2.3 (professional edition)
- плагин для poetry версии 1.1.5-212

Comment: Как устанавливали `poetry`?

Comment: Добавить путь к poetry в переменную окружения path через настройки системы, см. тут например про переменные окружения: https://lumpics.ru/environment-variables-in-windows-10/

Comment: @mironovmeow, через плагин с оф сайта jetbrains: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14307-poetry/versions

Comment: @insolor, пробовала, это не помогло

Comment: Перезагружались после этого?

Comment: @insolor, да было

Comment: @insolor, почему то с первого раза не сработало, но со второго еще как. Спасибо!